# What is the opposite of “Overridden“

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am looking for short word that I can use instead of “not overridden”.

For example:  “*All promotions that are not overridden at the store level are included in the forecast.*”

Comment: Perhaps *effective* or *in effect*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a good single word for what you describe, and your best bet is to turn the sentence around:

> The forecast includes all items *unless* overridden at the store level.
>
> The forecast includes all items *except those* overridden at the store level.

or even

> Items overridden at the store level are not included in the forecast.

Comment: I wouldn't use the "unless" example, as that could also mean the store overrides the decision to include it.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler: Yes, it wasn't clear from the original example just what they were overriding.

Answer (score 5):

In politics, they say *uphold* ("The Congress upheld the President's veto.") You could use *obey*, *follow*, *comply with*, or *observe*, but there's a lot to be said for *not override*.

Answer (score 5):

In court, an objection that is not "overridden" is, instead, **sustained**.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a proposal that is ***not overridden***, then that proposal is ***accepted*** or ***endorsed***.

Answer (score 1):

In technical senses the standard term is **default**. You customize the behavior of an application or a device by overriding the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a single word for what you want, but I can re-write the sentence you give as:

> All promotions that take priority at the store level are included in the forecast.

To say that the promotion "takes priority at the store level" means that it is not overridden by any other promotion from other levels.

For a single word in a drop-down list, you could use "prioritized".

Comment: To my mind, that says the opposite of what he intends. To say that the store level takes priority would mean that it does override a promotion that was set at a different level either higher (region? corporate?) or lower (department?). It's possible I've misunderstood either you or Ian, though.

Comment: @rhuffstedtler: He changed the sentence... give me a minute to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks,now how do I fit in a combo box?

Comment: @Ian: You could say that something has been "prioritized", though in your context it is a very specific meaning, you might want to have a little tooltip explaining what "prioritized" means.